# Comparing stored result of floating point addition to temporary in Fortran

Tags: floating-point, fortran, precision, gfortran

I noticed some behaviour with the `==`-operator for floating point types that seems strange to me. I know that i can not expect something like `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` to be `.true.` due to the limitations of floating point representation, and that therefore, floating point comparisons should usually be done with something like `abs(x - y) < tolerance`. However, i still expected this minimal program to output `T` in any case:

```
program main
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(0d0)
    real(kind=dp) :: a, b, c

    a = 4.4090680619790817d+002
    b = 1.0000000000000000d-004
    c = (a + b)

    print *, (c == (a + b))
end program
```

When compiling this program using gfortran 7.3.1 on 64-bit Manjaro Linux with

```
gfortran -o a.out minimal_example.F90 && a.out
```

i in fact do get the output `T`. However, when compiling and executing a 32-bit executable with

```
gfortran -m32 -o a.out minimal_example.F90 && a.out
```

the result is `F`. To me it seems like storing the result of the addition slightly changes its value, as the difference `abs(c - (a + b))` is roughly `2.5E-014`. I do not really understand why though, as all variables are of the same kind, so should the temporary `a + b` not have the same precision and therefore fit in `c` without any conversion error?

Trying this with several randomly generated values in the interval [0,1) for `a` and `b` repeated this observation. The comparison in the 64-bit executable was always `.true.`, while 25% of the attempts with the 32-bit executable resulted in `.false.`.

What is the reason for this behaviour? In particular, why is there a difference between the 64-bit and 32-bit executable?

Comment: I suspect the compiler is evaluating expressions with extra precision and discarding that precision when storing. Some languages, such as C, permit that. However, I am not familiar with the FORTRAN standard. The consequence would be that `a+b` has the extra precision of a long double, and its value is changed when rounded to a double to store in `c`, so `c` does not have the same value as `a+b`.

Comment: If you want similar results between 32- and 64-bit modes, you must set an sse option in the 32-bit, e.g. -msse2 ; 32-bit default uses extra precision, as mentioned above.  Extra precision normally gives you some additional accuracy, except that you don't have control over where it is used (and so it will break a few algorithms such as Kahan summation).  The -ffloat-store option is very slow running, so can't normally be recommended, unless you want to verify it gives the same result as sse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, using == (or .eq., for nostalgically inclined FORTRAN-programmers) on reals is advised against. Compilers tend to print warnings when you do (try compiler option -Wall for gfortran!).

Of course, one may still wonder what goes on inside a computer when you do so anyway.  One of FORTRAN's strengths s that the compiler has the freedom to shuffle calculations around, change their order, optimize-out certain variables, etcetera, as long as the result conforms to FORTRAN standards. As @Eric Postpischil points out: one of the things that may happen is that double precision variables are converted to a higher accuracy during a calculation, and only converted back to double precision when the calculation is done.

In your case, my guess would be that (a+b) is calculated in that higher precision, while c has been converted to double precision, and is therefore not the same.  I expect different behaviors for different compilers (ifort? the PGI-compiler?), and for different compiler-options (-fpexact, -O3 etcetera).

In short, I'd advise testing with a function like

```
 function same(a,b) result(eq)
 implicit none
     real, intent(in) :: a, b
     logical :: eq
     real, parameter :: very_small = 1e-10 ! or another very small value
     eq = abs(a-b) < very_small * abs(a)
 end function same
```

*Couldn't let the issue go just yet, so I tested a few compiler options on my
lubuntu.*

Oddly enough, the -m32 seems to have little effect on the result:

```
gfortran -m32  compare_reals.f90 && ./a.out
  F
gfortran compare_reals.f90 && ./a.out
  F
gfortran -m32 -ffloat-store compare_reals.f90 && ./a.out
 T
gfortran -m32 -O3 compare_reals.f90 && ./a.out
 TFloating point comparisons
gfortran -ffloat-store compare_reals.f90 && ./a.out
 T
gfortran -O3 compare_reals.f90 && ./a.out
 T
```

From the online documentation of gfortran, I found some information which
I assume explains the observations:

> -ffloat-store:
>
> Do not store floating point variables in registers, and inhibit other options that might change whether a floating point value is
>   taken from a register or memory.
>
> This option prevents undesirable excess precision on machines such as the 68000 where the floating registers (of the 68881) keep more
>   precision than a double is supposed to have. Similarly for the x86
>   architecture. For most programs, the excess precision does only good,
>   but a few programs rely on the precise definition of IEEE floating
>   point. Use -ffloat-store for such programs, after modifying them to
>   store all pertinent intermediate computations into variables

Comment: `a,b,c` are all double precision in this example.

Comment: @agentp you're absolutely right. Thanks for pointing that out, I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I am aware how to compare reals properly, this question is in fact about what happens if one still does it with the `==`-operator. I edited the question to clarify that. The second part of your answer is very helpful, with `-ffloat-store` i do get `T` with the 32-bit version. The description of the flag looks exactly like the explanation i was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is Fortran, not FORTRAN. There was no `==` in the old FORTRAN, just `.eq.`.